# Woocommerce orders not being received by PayPal, but email suggests otherwise

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

Having a nightmare with this and cannot find a solution anywhere - the only similar issues I find are the exact opposite problem!

Placing an order using PayPal (standard) at checkout puts the order 'On hold' in wp, but completes on the front end and the user even receives the PayPal receipt so are none the wiser. In the PayPal business account there is nothing.

Interestingly, PayPal express checkout works fine! So the account is definitely setup correctly. Something I have noticed is that the receipt from the express checkout transaction and from the standard have different Merchant names - the standard one (the one not working)has the name@emailaddress.com rather than the merchant name. This would suggest that this is the issue, but I've been into the business settings and checked this as well as the Woocommerce settings and everything is in order.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For Woocommerce PayPal standard you have to enable Auto return url and Notification url(Instant payment notification) which will update the order status on your woocommerce. Refer the following URL link: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-standard/ and enable both Auto return & Instant payment notification settings on the Merchant/Business PayPal account. Please note that Merchant PayPal account is not linked with any other website.

PayPal Express checkout is recommended: https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have this setup already. I also have express setup and confirm that it is working, it's only the standard that doesn't! A quick fix would be to only have PayPal express on the site, but the only problem with that is it does not allow the user to have a different address for delivery which is really important! Unless I've missed something there and it is possible?

Comment: Express checkout is recommended, shipping address details is passed over to PayPal on the normal checkout flow. On the PayPal shortcut button, consumer can change the address on the PayPal review page and complete the payment.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you just stick with Express Checkout.  It has many more features and options than PayPal Standard.  I would recommend the [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/), though, which is the one PayPal reps would recommend as well if you talk to them.